# Angular is not displaying data in table row. ng-repeat is not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm trying to use Angularjs. The problem is, ng-repeat not working when it is in the route. It works when it is not in route.

Here's what I have so far:
See the links..

this works well...
http://plnkr.co/edit/1syQFJdMyRUYncBrREue?p=preview

but in this, it didn't work now..(navigate in persons)
http://plnkr.co/edit/gsi2mZpnU0YJUUOa20DO?p=preview

html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Confirm Dialog Box</title>
 <!-- 
    in the link above i create a custom dialog box
 -->
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="loglistController">
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td onclick="showDialog()" ng-click="showInEdit(x)">{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td onclick="showDialog()" ng-click="showInEdit(x)">{{ x.Country }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>


             <div id="white-background">
</div>
<div id="dlgbox">
    <div id="dlg-header"><h3>Information</h3></div>
    <div id="dlg-body">
      Name <input type="text" ng-model="selectedPerson.Name" /><br/>
      Country <input type="text" ng-model="selectedPerson.Country" /><br/>


    </div>
    <div id="dlg-footer">
        <button onclick="dlgOK()">Update</button>
        <button onclick="dlgCancel()">Exit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

angular

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.controller('loglistController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.data=[];
    $scope.selectedPerson={ Name:"",Country:""}; 

            $http.get("loglistajax.php")
                .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});

    $scope.showInEdit=function(person){
    $scope.selectedPerson = person;
    };



 }]);
```

Comment: For starters, you've define MyApp and loglistController in app.js and list.html  Remove it from one or the other then see where you are.  My recommendation is to remove it from list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a (somewhat) [fixed plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Whi7T7pLmNbmNSfgJ4de?p=preview), however I found the following issues in your code:

- You have double controllers: `loglistController` is defined twice, once inside `app.js` and then again inside `list.html`.

  You wrote the following line

  `<tr ng-repeat="x in data">`

  Thinking it would read from `loglistController`'s `$scope.data` but your app seems to be considering the first controller, so your controller scope has no data properties. I solved replacing the controller in `app.js` with the one inside `list.html`.

  Thinking about it, I guess you are not allowed to put a route controller's code inside it's template, so you'd better avoid doing that in the future!
- Your `app.js`' `templateUrl` does not exists when url is `'/'` and this throws an error. I solved by replacing it with `'list.html'`. I'm quite sure it's not what you will want, but it was needed to make it work.

Comment: sorry it's kinda messy codes. I just recently learning angularjs in a messy way hahaha. Actually, I just recently learn coding. It's now clear for me. it's very detailed info.  It's working really fine now. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my [version](http://plnkr.co/edit/iXFT2HJzk9j0L7VtgrhM?p=preview)

I agree with most [points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361187/4534420) that **imbalind** mentioned.

Just would like to add few more:

- we should not instantiate same app multiple times (in original Plunker we had it in both index.html and list.html). Here are two cases:

  ```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']); //new instance of 'myApp' 

  var myApp = angular.module('myApp'); //simply handle to 'myApp'
  ```
- we had two `'loglistController'` that belong to same `angular.module`, which not going to work
- angular itself was loaded in both html files, not good.
- for that particular Plunker, fixed route in app.js:

  ```
  .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/index.html',
      controller: 'mainController'
  })
  ```
- and please don't mixup jQuery script, it will create a lot of confusion later...

Comment: sorry it's kinda messy codes. I just recently learning angularjs in a messy way hahaha. Actually, I just recently learn coding.  thanks for some info :)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your $http request is resolving?

```
 $http.get("loglistajax.php").then(function (response) {
     $scope.names = response.data.records;
 }).catch(function(response) {
     console.log("I am failing to resolve a non-2xx response");
 });
```

initially try without the $http request using dummy data n build up slowly!

FYI ...

you can do ...

```
$scope.names = $http.get("loglistajax.php");
```

Which only works if the HTTP request resolve!

PS neither of your plunkr's show anything!